# Begin and end of all sequences

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the beginning and end of all the sequences (larger than 1 number) from a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sequence` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `sequence` (`id`) VALUES (1), (3), (4), (6), (7), (8), (10), (11), (12), (13), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26);
```

Referring to [this website](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/06/find-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-with-sql/), in stead of finding the gaps, I would like to get the 'start' and 'stop' of all sequences. So I would expect a result like this:

```
+-----+----+
|start|stop|
+-----+----+
|    3|   4|
|    6|   8|
|   10|  13|
|   15|  19|
|   21|  26|
+-----+----+
```

I came up with the following query which gives me the right starting positions, but not the ending positions.

```
SELECT
  start, stop
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.id AS start, MIN(t3.id) AS stop
  FROM
    sequence t1
    INNER JOIN sequence t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sequence t3 ON t1.id < t3.id
  GROUP BY
    t1.id
  ORDER BY 1
) x

WHERE
  x.start NOT IN (
    SELECT
      MIN(t3.id) AS stop
    FROM
      sequence t1
      INNER JOIN sequence t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sequence t3 ON t1.id < t3.id
    GROUP BY
      t1.id
    ORDER BY 1
  )
GROUP BY
  start;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, which I'd like to share with the world:

```
SELECT
  l.id AS start,
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(a.id) AS id
    FROM
      sequence a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sequence b ON a.id + 1 = b.id
    WHERE
      b.id IS NULL
      AND a.id >= l.id
  ) AS stop
FROM
  sequence l
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sequence r ON r.id + 1 = l.id
WHERE
  r.id IS NULL
```

This will also take the 'loners' into account, but they can be filtered out easily with `stop - start != 0`.